# Three promises with HTTP

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I had to do three HTTP Post requests in my code. The first two work, I debug the code and they return the correct value, but the last one returns undefined.
I made these three requisitions due to one depending on the response of the other.

login button:

```
goToMenu() {
this.dados_login = [];
this.dados_login.push({
  "CPF": this.cpfLogin,
  "Senha": this.senhaLogin
})
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(this.dados_login["0"]), options)
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) => {
      var json_token = (response as any)._body;
      var parsed = JSON.parse(json_token);

      var arr = [];

      for (var x in parsed) {
        arr.push(parsed[x]);
      }

      this.token = arr[0];

      this.carregaEmpresas();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var json_error = (error as any)._body;
      var parsed = JSON.parse(json_error);

      var arr = [];

      for (var x in parsed) {
        arr.push(parsed[x]);
      }

      this.error_login = arr[0];

      this.presentAlert(this.error_login)
    });
});
```

function that carries companies, the error occurs here because it is not returned nothing to it

```
carregaEmpresas(newpage: boolean = false) {
console.log(this.cpfLogin);
this.abreCarregando();

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.EmpresaProvider.getEmpresas(this.token, this.cpfLogin)
    .then((response) => {
      var json_emp = (response as any)._body;
      var parsed = JSON.parse(json_emp);

      var arr_emp = [];

      for (var x in parsed) {
        arr_emp.push(parsed[x]);
      }

      this.lista_empresas = arr_emp;

      this.objEmp = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.lista_empresas.length; i++) {
        this.obj = {
          label:
            this.lista_empresas[i].Valor,
          type: 'radio',
          value: this.lista_empresas[i].Chave
        }
        this.objEmp.push(this.obj);
      }

      this.fechaCarregando();
      this.selectEmpresa();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var json_error = (error as any)._body;
      var parsed = JSON.parse(json_error);

      var arr = [];

      for (var x in parsed) {
        arr.push(parsed[x]);
      }

      this.error_login = arr[0];

      this.presentAlert(this.error_login)
    });
});
```

provider role:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.post(this.baseApiPath, JSON.stringify(this.cpf_usuario["0"]), options)
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) => {
      var empresa = (response as any)._body;
      var parsed = JSON.parse(empresa);

      var arr = [];

      for (var x in parsed) {
        arr.push(parsed[x]);
      }

      this.empresa_cod = arr[0].Chave.split("/", 1);
      var urlFilial = this.apiFilial + this.empresa_cod["0"];
      return this.http.get(urlFilial, options);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var json_error = (error as any)._body;
      var parsed = JSON.parse(json_error);

      var arr = [];

      for (var x in parsed) {
        arr.push(parsed[x]);
      }

      return arr[0];
    });
});
```

GetEmpresas Code:

```
getEmpresas(token: string, Cpf: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.cpf_usuario.push({ "Cpf": Cpf });

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.http.post(this.baseApiPath, JSON.stringify(this.cpf_usuario["0"]), options)
          .toPromise()
          .then((response) => {
            var empresa = (response as any)._body;
            var parsed = JSON.parse(empresa);

            var arr = [];

            for (var x in parsed) {
              arr.push(parsed[x]);
            }

            this.empresa_cod = arr[0].Chave.split("/", 1);
            var urlFilial = this.apiFilial + this.empresa_cod["0"];
            return this.http.get(urlFilial, options)
              .toPromise()
              .then((response) => {
                var json_emp = (response as any)._body;
                var parsed = JSON.parse(json_emp);

                var arr_emp = [];

                for (var x in parsed) {
                  arr_emp.push(parsed[x]);
                }

                this.emp = arr_emp;
                return arr_emp;
              })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            var json_error = (error as any)._body;
            var parsed = JSON.parse(json_error);

            var arr = [];

            for (var x in parsed) {
              arr.push(parsed[x]);
            }

            return arr[0];
          });
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the `undefined`?  The code is hard to understand without seeing the function that the third code block belongs to.  I do notice that you are never resolving or rejecting any of the promises you create with `new Promise`.  In the first two cases, this may make no apparent difference, but in the third, it would cause the promise to never complete.  This still doesn't explain why you are getting `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This code is very confusing and I find it interesting to develop another one. Anyway, how can I make a promise with three HTTP calls or else make the calls without promisse?

Comment: As a general pattern, if all the code were in one function, `this.http.post(...).then((response1) => { return this.http.post(...); }).then((response2) => { return this.http.get(...); })` would work.  Or better, use an async function with: `let response1 = await this.http.post(...); let response2 = await this.http.post(...); return await this.http.get(...);`.  If you want help fixing the existing code, I need an example that's [complete enough](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I can understand how all the parts interact.  In particular, I need to see the declaration of `getEmpresas`.

Comment: Okay, I've gotten GetEmpresas code.

Comment: Instead of adding an answer, please edit the question and add the `GetEmpresas` code to the question.

Comment: Post edited. You now have the complete getEmpresas code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a draft because I'm not sure I've found the problem yet, but I need to share more code than will fit in a comment.

The first thing I would try is removing the `new Promise` because you aren't resolving or rejecting those promises anyway.  I'd also try removing the `window.setTimeout`.  At that point, it looks like `getEmpresas` will return a promise for the `arr_emp` that is the result of parsing the final `get` response.  If you do that, then the `then` handler in `carregaEmpresas` will receive the `arr_emp` that was generated in `getEmpresas`, so you should just name the parameter `arr_emp` and not try to parse it again.  The code at this point is:

```
class MyClass {
    // Dummy declarations to suppress TypeScript errors
    dados_login;
    cpfLogin;
    senhaLogin;
    http;
    url;
    token;
    error_login;
    presentAlert;
    abreCarregando;
    lista_empresas;
    objEmp;
    obj;
    fechaCarregando;
    selectEmpresa;

    EmpresaProvider: EmpresaProvider;

    goToMenu() {
        this.dados_login = [];
        this.dados_login.push({
          "CPF": this.cpfLogin,
          "Senha": this.senhaLogin
        })
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

          this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(this.dados_login["0"]), options)
            .toPromise()
            .then((response) => {
              var json_token = (response as any)._body;
              var parsed = JSON.parse(json_token);

              var arr = [];

              for (var x in parsed) {
                arr.push(parsed[x]);
              }

              this.token = arr[0];

              this.carregaEmpresas();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              var json_error = (error as any)._body;
              var parsed = JSON.parse(json_error);

              var arr = [];

              for (var x in parsed) {
                arr.push(parsed[x]);
              }

              this.error_login = arr[0];

              this.presentAlert(this.error_login)
            });
    }

    carregaEmpresas(newpage: boolean = false) {
        console.log(this.cpfLogin);
        this.abreCarregando();

          this.EmpresaProvider.getEmpresas(this.token, this.cpfLogin)
            .then((/*response*/ arr_emp) => {
              /*
              var json_emp = (response as any)._body;
              var parsed = JSON.parse(json_emp);

              var arr_emp = [];

              for (var x in parsed) {
                arr_emp.push(parsed[x]);
              }
              */

              this.lista_empresas = arr_emp;

              this.objEmp = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < this.lista_empresas.length; i++) {
                this.obj = {
                  label:
                    this.lista_empresas[i].Valor,
                  type: 'radio',
                  value: this.lista_empresas[i].Chave
                }
                this.objEmp.push(this.obj);
              }

              this.fechaCarregando();
              this.selectEmpresa();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              var json_error = (error as any)._body;
              var parsed = JSON.parse(json_error);

              var arr = [];

              for (var x in parsed) {
                arr.push(parsed[x]);
              }

              this.error_login = arr[0];

              this.presentAlert(this.error_login)
            });
    }
}

class EmpresaProvider {
    // Dummy declarations to suppress TypeScript errors
    cpf_usuario;
    http;
    baseApiPath;
    empresa_cod;
    apiFilial;
    emp;

    getEmpresas(token: string, Cpf: string) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.cpf_usuario.push({ "Cpf": Cpf });

            return this.http.post(this.baseApiPath, JSON.stringify(this.cpf_usuario["0"]), options)
              .toPromise()
              .then((response) => {
                var empresa = (response as any)._body;
                var parsed = JSON.parse(empresa);

                var arr = [];

                for (var x in parsed) {
                  arr.push(parsed[x]);
                }

                this.empresa_cod = arr[0].Chave.split("/", 1);
                var urlFilial = this.apiFilial + this.empresa_cod["0"];
                return this.http.get(urlFilial, options)
                  .toPromise()
                  .then((response) => {
                    var json_emp = (response as any)._body;
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(json_emp);

                    var arr_emp = [];

                    for (var x in parsed) {
                      arr_emp.push(parsed[x]);
                    }

                    this.emp = arr_emp;
                    return arr_emp;
                  })
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                var json_error = (error as any)._body;
                var parsed = JSON.parse(json_error);

                var arr = [];

                for (var x in parsed) {
                  arr.push(parsed[x]);
                }

                return arr[0];
              });

      }
}
```

Please try this code (integrated into your original program of course) and let me know if it works or otherwise what is the exact error and what line it occurs on.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks from Brazil.